# Child theme function.php causes fatal error

Tags: functions, child-theme

When I copy an exact copy of the function.php file to the child theme folder I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare archi_theme_setup() (previously declared in /home/desi3442/public_html/wp-content/themes/archi-child/functions.php:28) in /home/desi3442/public_html/wp-content/themes/archi/functions.php on line 71
```

I dont quite understand the error cause its pulling function.php from the main theme files when the child functions.php is supposed to overwrite it correct?

Comment: do **not** copy an exact copy of functions.php into the child theme - read https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php

Comment: Follow this guide for creating a <a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes">child theme</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the same function exists in the parent.

```
archi_theme_setup()
```

Since you are under the same namespace there will be a name collision — PHP cannot hold two functions with the same name.

[image]

When you set the child theme as the active one child theme `functions.php` will load first and then the other one frorm the parent.

---

You cannot just copy paste the code. 
Check the theme developer to provide you the child theme functions.php template.

Or use the empty template with the comments part in front.